# Spaces in OU causing drupal ldapgroups lookup to deny login

Tags: drupal, ldap

I'm trying to configure mapping of LDAP Groups to Drupal roles.

The DN for the group that I have been given contains a space in the OU:

```
CN=CommunityUsers,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=TLD,DC=AD
```

Drupal is authenticating if there is no space, but under no circumstances can I have the space removed.

Can I change the way I specify the DN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms gave us every indication that it was a problem with spaces.  It was simply that the ldapgroups module does not deal with nested groups.